# how to disable automount of usb drive at boot in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: automount

I have a RDX Drive (USB Intern) for backups on the Server. When the backups are done the Server does a restart. It then mounts the RDX Drive. I can get the Cartridge out by pushing and holding the Eject Button until the Cartridge comes out. But there must be a way to disable this. I have set dconf-editor so that the auto mount is disabled for all users and that works, RDX Drive does not automount when I put it in. I tried with 00-media-automount and user local, but nothing seems to work. I change Cartridges every day, so setting /etc/fstab to noauto is not the solution either. Any Ideas?

Comment: Include in fstab not to mount, then mount in a script before backup and unmount after the backup is not a solution?

Comment: systemctl mask udisks2, seems to have stop the automounting. Will this have any other efects on the Server?

Comment: Other than entirely disabling automounting? No.

Comment: Thanks this exactly what I want.